# my api does not return the complete object

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm starting with this from the APIs the .netcore and I have a foreign key and when I do the query the value is null

[image]

in that case, I read that the include is used to obtain its value, but when I use it it does not show all the values ​​of the table and in the breakpoints, I see that it does a radial effect and it does not pass from there

[image]

My controller

```cs
public class ComidasController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly testcoreContext _context;

        public ComidasController(testcoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Comidas
        [HttpGet]
        public List<Comida> GetComida()
        {
            var prueba =_context.Comida.ToList();
            return prueba;
        }

        // GET: api/Comidas/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Comida>> GetComida(int id)
        {
            var comida = await _context.Comida.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=> x.Id==id);

            if (comida == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return comida;
        }
```

My classes

```cs
{
    public partial class Comida
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Type { get; set; }

        public virtual Types TypeNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
public partial class Types
    {


        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comida> Comida { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Didi u try to find instead ? var comida = await _context.Comida.FindAsync(id)

Comment: your complete object contains circular dependency. Using Data Transfer Object (DTO) preferred in such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ilkerkaran said, you're getting a circular dependency in your JSON, you can tell your app to ignore this by adding the below to your startup.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

Comment: I already copied that code in the servicesConfigure, but now the api returns me like this

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v_qMZc1rFcgGsFa5EZxSvenCUgSLxhGy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @PedroSosa What is your expected result?

Comment: @PedroSosa looks OK to me, what are you expecting?

Comment: then always return comida inside the type ?, because I have seen examples in which it does not repeat the main object inside the secondary and I hoped that it would not do it

Comment: @PedroSosa if I understood that correctly you could have a list of Ids instead (public virtual ICollection<int> Comidas) instead of the object, otherwise they'll just keep referencing each other

Answer (score 0):

your complete object contains circular dependency. Using Data Transfer Object (DTO) preferred in such. However, you could use anonymous types:

```
await _context.Comida.Where(x=> x.Id==id)
.Select(comida => new {
    id= comida.Id,
    name= comida,Name,
    type= comida.Type,
    typeNavigation= comida.TypeNavigation })
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```